# How to pass parameters in named route in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to pass the parameters in the url in my blade template, the url is:

```
href="/finance/invoices/download/{{ $invoice->file_path }}
```

and in web.php the route is defined as:

```
Route::get('invoices/download/{year}/{month}/{file}','InvoiceController@download')->name('download');
```

and the file is stored in the database as :

> 2018/07/invoiceberry_invoice_template_1.docx

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

For add to previous answer, you make do this:

```
route('download',['year' => $year, 'month' => $month, 'file' => $file]);
```

Comment: it is giving an error as Undefined variable: year (View: C:\wamp64\www\Blog\employee-portal\resources\views\finance\invoice\edit.blade.php)

Comment: @lalitmehta because you don`t pass $year into your edit.blade.php, check controller method

Comment: in my controller the download function is as follows :public function download($year, $month, $file, $inline = true)
    {
        $headers = [
            'content-type' => 'application/pdf',
        ];

        $file_path = FileHelper::getFilePath($year, $month, $file);

        if (!$file_path) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($inline) {
            return Response::make(Storage::get($file_path), 200, $headers);
        }

        return Storage::download($file_path);
    }

Comment: and my filehelper is as follows:public static function getFilePath($year, $month, $file)
    {
        $filePath =  $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $file;

        if (!Storage::exists($filePath)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $filePath;
    }

Comment: @lalitmehta no, check controller method, who reterned edit.blade.php

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying, download method above is being called when I am running my code

Comment: @lalitmehta i don`t understand you. You call route() function with out defined params life $year

Comment: that is where I am stuck right now. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple you can do

```
{{ route('download', 1) }}
```

If you want pass more than one parameters you should pass as an array like this:

```
{{ route('download', ['year'=>1987]) }}
{{ route('download', ['year'=>1987, 'month'=>june, 'day'=>11]) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the parameters to a route using `route()` helper.

Which takes the second parameters as a array.

```
route('download',[$year, $month, $file]);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it is giving an error as Undefined variable: year (View: C:\wamp64\www\Blog\employee-portal\resources\views\finance\invoice\edit.blade.php)